# pic 16f84a timer / counting code not behaving as expected

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

I am basically learning about pic external interrupts on the pic16f84a microcontroller. Basically i want to count every press of a button attached to pin B0 (RB0/T0CKI) and display results from a seven segment display. I am using hitech c compiler.

```
#include<htc.h>
__CONFIG(WDTE_OFF& PWRTE_OFF & CP_OFF);
char get7SegmentCode(char value)
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case 0b00000000:
            return (char)0b00111111 ; //0 code
        case 0b00000001:
            return (char)0b00110000 ; //1 code
        case 0b00000010:
            return (char)0b01011011  ; //2 code
        case 0b00000011:
            return (char)0b010011111 ; //3 code
        default:
            return (char)0b00000000 ; //all  code
    }
}
void main()
{
    //declare portb for output and porta upper 4 pins for output and lower 4 for input
    TRISA=0b00001111;
    TRISB=0b00000000;
    CLRWDT();//clear watchdog timer
    TMR0=0;
    OPTION_REG = 0b00111000;//RBPU:PORTB pull-ups are disabled,
    //INTEDG:Interrupt on falling edge of RB0/INT pin
    //T0CS:Transition on RA4/T0CKI pin
    //T0SE:Increment on high-to-low transition on RA4/T0CKI pin
    //PSA:Prescaler assigned to the WDT
    while(1)
    {
        char timerval= TMR0;//read tmr0 into variable
        char restrictedtimerval= timerval & 0x0f;//force upper 4bits to zero to restrict value to 0 - f
        PORTB= get7SegmentCode(restrictedtimerval);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when I simulate this code in proteus vsm, the seven segment display just shows '0' no matter how many times i press the switch. Why is this happening?
PS: This is my circuit.
[image: circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin `RA4/T0CKI` is fifth bit named RA4 of port A.
So your initiation code must be

```
TRISA=0b00011111;
```

instead

```
TRISA=0b00001111;
```